# The non-trivial zeros of $L(s, \chi)$ are symmetrically placed with respect to the critical line

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Let $\chi$ be a primitive Dirichlet character modulo $q$. My book says that "The non-trivial zeros of $L(s, \chi)$ are symmetrically placed with respect to the critical line $\sigma=1/2$". Now, if $\rho$ is a non-trivial zero of $L(s, \chi)$, then, by the functional equation, one has that $1-\rho$ is a zero of $L(s, \overline{\chi})$, and so $1-\overline{\rho}$ is a zero of $L(s, \chi)$ (since $\overline{L(s, \chi)}=L(\overline{s}, \overline{\chi})$). But, in general, $\rho$ and $1-\overline{\rho}$ are not symmetrically placed with respect to the critical line. Am I wrong?

Comment: This is why we write the functional equation as $\Lambda(s) = Q^{-s} \Gamma(s+a)L(s,\chi) = \overline{\Lambda(1-\overline{s})}$. It shows the non-trivial zeros come in pair $\sigma+it, 1-\sigma+it$ and that $\Lambda(1/2+it)$ is real for $t$ real

Comment: @reuns it is *not* true in your comment that $\Lambda(1/2 + it)$ is real for $t$ real for $L$-functions of nonquadratic characters.  You left out the root number $W(\chi)$ on the right side of the functional equation: this number need not be $1$.  When $u$ is a square root of $W(\chi)$, which is only well-defined up to a sign, $u\overline{u} = 1$ and the ratio $\Lambda(1/2 + it)/u$ is real for $t$ real.

Comment: @KCd Yes thank you I'm aware of that, makes sense to add the (square) root number into $\Lambda$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $\rho = \beta + i \gamma$. Then $1- \overline{\rho} = (1-\beta) + i \gamma$ is indeed the reflection of $\rho$ with respect to the critical line $\mathrm{Re}(s) = 1/2$.

Notice that if $\chi$ is a real character, then $L(\rho, \chi) = 0$ iff $1 - \rho$ is also a zero of $L(s, \chi)$ iff $\overline{\rho}$ is a zero of $L(s, \chi)$.